# How do I hook up a referencing outlet in Interface Bulider for a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I want to access a UIImage programmatically... i.e. myImage.hidden = TRUE; etc.  I can do this fine for UILabel but when I repeat the process for UIImage it doesn't work.  Specifically when I drag the blue line in Interface Builder over the icon I don't get a popup menu like I do when using UILabel.

Perhaps using UIImageView instead of UIImage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An UIImage is not a view that can be added via Interface Builder.  In order to display a UIImage you either need to override the drawRect method of whatever view you want to display it in, or use a UIImageView.

Using a UIImageView will allow you to set it as an IBOutlet and reference it in your controller.